# Can item/view styles be set on an Android listview item from the data in the list?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list populated from a sqlite database with data values ranging from -1 to 1. Is there any way to set the background color for the negative items to red and the positive items to green? A similar effect could be had by adding a green up arrow to the item view for positive and a red down arrow image for negative values. Another example might be a to-do list with items color coded by a priority value. In ios this would occur in cellforrowat indexpath and on windows phone/silverlight it would be done by binding a dependency property to the data. Can this be achieved with Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.. in getView method

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
     ImageView imageview= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("-")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.uparrow);
   //or set background colour of those views here..
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.downarrow);
    }


    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: this is definitely leading me in the right direction, still working on it. Since I'm using a cursor I'm extending cursoradapter

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do on Android. Each list item is updated whenever the list comes into view, there is a getView method in a ListAdapter where you would set the value of the list item.

So you would have an list_item.xml layout for just the list items.
in the Custom ListAdapter you can set the color of the background in the getView() method where you set the inflated (View) list_item. setBackground().

Check these links out:
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

Answer (score 0):

In your getview method in your adapter you could check that value and programmaticly change the color or drawable of every item as its being created.